# How to implement a python-like input function in Rust using generic types?

Tags: rust

I made a python-like input function to get stdin and return a String. It was working fine, I got the result and it was parsing into whatever numeric type needed. But, I decided to move parsing to the function and use a generic type on it, then I got an error.

Here's the code:

```rust
fn input<T>(text: &str) -> T {
    let mut input = String::new();

    println!("{}", text);
    std::io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Erro ao ler valor");

    let input = input.trim().parse::<T>().expect("Erro ao ler valor");

    return input;
}
```

The error in compilation:

```
let input = input.trim().parse::<T>().expect("Erro ao ler valor");
                         ^^^^^ the trait `FromStr` is not implemented for `T`
```

Also, in VSCode, this message is shown:

```
main.rs(9, 11): consider restricting type parameter `T`: `: std::str::FromStr`
```

*I think I could use enumeration to fix this, but it would be hard to write down every possible type accepted by println, and use conditional statement seems to be even worse. I've been studying Rust for three days so far and I don't really know the right approach.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler tells you what to do:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

fn input<T: FromStr>(text: &str) -> T {
//        ^^^^^^^^^
```

This *bounds* the generic type `T` and says that it must implement the [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) trait, which is required for `.parse::<T>()` to work (the `parse` function bounds on `T: FromStr` as well).

Further reading:

- [Traits as parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters)

Comment: Thanks man, I finally managed to do this. Just a doubt, these traits are like interfaces that validate the behavior of an object, right? so limiting the behavior of the generic type guarantees that it is always a valid object?

Comment: @Smith Your terminology is a bit wrong but you have the basic idea. A trait describes the set of operations that must be valid for a particular _type,_ not object. The trait can then be implemented on various types. (Trait associated functions do not have to be "methods" -- `FromStr` is actually a good example of this. Note that the only input to the `FromStr::from_str` function is a `&str`; the "implementing" type `Self` is only seen in the return type.